# Using User32InitializeImmEntryTable on Winx64?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

User32InitializeImmEntryTable is used by https://github.com/jay/gethooks to get SharedInfo which in turn is used to get a list of global event hooks.

That program works on Win32 but not Win7x64, how can that be fixed?

There are separate problems depending on whether you build for Win32 or x64.

On x64 build, the code in question that fails is from prog.c:

```
p = (char *)User32InitializeImmEntryTable;
for( i = 0; i < 127; ++i )
{
    if( ( *p++ == 0x50 ) && ( *p == 0x68 ) )
    {
        *( (char *)&SharedInfo + 0 ) = *++p;
        *( (char *)&SharedInfo + 1 ) = *++p;
        *( (char *)&SharedInfo + 2 ) = *++p;
        *( (char *)&SharedInfo + 3 ) = *++p;
        break;
    }
}
```

0x50, 0x68 (push eax) is not found.

On Win32 build the above works but EnumDesktopsW doesn't, in function add_all_desktops of desktop.c.

Also I'm not sure fixing that part will allow the program to run properly on x64, but I imagine it's a start. I'm also not sure whether it's better to build Win32 or x64 executable, which one is easier to get it working?

I hope this is an ok question, AFAIK getting a list of the apps that create global hooks is a good thing, say for finding keyloggers, troubleshooting or w/e. So fixing that gethooks program would benefit the community, which ever way it ends up being fixed. Any downvote at all and I will delete immediately I promise.

Comment: this falls in the category of grossly unsupported. If I were to guess it's because the calling convention on win64 is universally* `__fastcall` not `__stdcall`

*mangling is all that changes, vectorcall is the only exception to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7 it's very simple:

```
SHAREDINFO *SharedInfo = (SHAREDINFO *)GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("user32"), "gSharedInfo");
```

But Windows 8/10 is a different story and am going to open a new question.